# Semi-transparent markers in Matlab Figures

Tags: matlab, transparency, matlab-figure

I want to plot a scatter plot with filled markers and make them semi-transparent so when two or more markers overlap, the overlapping area will be more opaque.

I naively thought

```
sg = scatter(rand(1000,1),rand(1000,1), 'filled');
alpha(0.5)
```

would work, but it doesn't. Also

```
set(get(sg, 'Children'), 'FaceAlpha', 0.2)
```

doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plot circles with alpha values in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893513/plot-circles-with-alpha-values-in-matlab)

Comment: Maybe there wasn't a straightforward way to do that by the time this question was asked but now there's a way. Not sure since which version though. [See this link.](https://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab/mw/graphics-ex36949892-create-scatter-chart-with-transparency).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot change the alpha values of the plot markers in `scatter`. One solution would be to [`patch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/patch.html) to draw markers yourself. Alpha values can be set for `patch()` objects and you will get the desired effect when markers overlap. However, this can get quite cumbersome and will need to be customized to your needs.

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893513/plot-circles-with-alpha-values-in-matlab), where the function defined in the question does exactly that. You can use that as a starting point and work from there.

Comment: Well, that's what I guessed and feared. Still, I'll leave the question open for a while just to make sure no one with an answer is hanging around. Thanks!

Comment: I concluded that there was no answer (well, no way to set the alpha values of plot markers) and still use my ag_plot_little_circles function.

Answer (score 10):

Here's some sample matlab code that makes transparent scatterplot points with patch objects:

```
x=randn(5000,1)*20;
y= randn(5000,1)*20;
t= 0:pi/10:2*pi;
figure();
for i=1:size(x)
    pb=patch((sin(t)+ x(i)),(cos(t)+y(i)),'b','edgecolor','none');
    alpha(pb,.1);
end
```

Comment: Really a nice suggestion. I would like to add that, if one is interested in scaling the patch-size then simply apply multiplication to the sin() or cos() calls, e.g. sin(t)/3 would make the patches smaller.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually go about this without using patch. The example below uses the hidden MarkerHandle to let you access transparency. All you have to provide is the rgb code for the color you want and the transparency level on the same scale. The example below plots the random markers in a transparent red with 10% opacity by setting `FaceColorData` to `uint8(255*[1;0;0;0.1])`

```
sg = scatter(rand(1000,1),rand(1000,1), 'filled');
sMarkers=sg.MarkerHandle; %hidden marker handle
sMarkers.FaceColorData = uint8(255*[1;0;0;0.1]); %fourth element allows setting alpha
sMarkers.EdgeColorData = uint8(255*[1;0;0;0]); %set edge color in a similar way
```

EDIT: It seems that MATLAB will change these properties without warning when you resize, save...or apparently just look at it funny.

Based on http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/plot-markers-transparency-and-color-gradient

Comment: Only for Matlab 2014 and after.

Comment: Take note of the warnings about using `legend` and the workaround provided at that same blog post.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about the previous versions, but 
Matlab 2016 seems to have the feature you are looking for:

sg = scatter(rand(1000,1),rand(1000,1), 'filled');

sg.MarkerFaceAlpha = 0.1;

Comment: Interestingly, with Matlab 2019 the plot handle still doesn't have this property. For scatter though you also have MarkerEdgeAlpha.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function I used to create a semi-transparent scatter.

* This is a modified version of [user2149589](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2149589/user2149589) answer (a bit more matlab-friendly).

```
function scatterPoints = transparentScatter(x,y,sizeOfCirlce,opacity)
% usage example:
% scatterPoints = transparentScatter(randn(5000,1),randn(5000,1),0.1,0.05);
% set(scatterPoints,'FaceColor',[1,0,0]);


    defaultColors = get(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder');
    assert(size(x,2)  == 1 && size(y,2)  == 1 , 'x and y should be column vectors');
    t= 0:pi/10:2*pi;

    rep_x = repmat(x',[size(t,2),1]);
    rep_y = repmat(y',[size(t,2),1]);
    rep_t = repmat(t',[ 1, size(x,1)]);

    scatterPoints = patch((sizeOfCirlce*sin(rep_t)+ rep_x),(sizeOfCirlce*cos(rep_t)+rep_y),defaultColors(1,:),'edgecolor','none');
    alpha(scatterPoints,opacity);

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above is a nice little function (for those of us still pre-2014b), but can be improved with a call to 'DataAspectRatio' and an adjustment of the patch size to make sure that the circles look like circles:

```
function scatterPoints = transparentScatter(x,y,sizeOfCirlce,opacity)
% usage example:
% scatterPoints = transparentScatter(randn(5000,1),randn(5000,1),0.1,0.05);
% set(scatterPoints,'FaceColor',[1,0,0]);

    dRatio = get(gca,'DataAspectRatio');
    dRatio = dRatio(1) / dRatio(2);
    defaultColors = get(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder');
    assert(size(x,2)  == 1 && size(y,2)  == 1 , 'x and y should be column vectors');
    t= 0:pi/10:2*pi;

    rep_x = repmat(x',[size(t,2),1]);
    rep_y = repmat(y',[size(t,2),1]);
    rep_t = repmat(t',[ 1, size(x,1)]);

    scatterPoints = patch((dRatio*sizeOfCirlce*sin(rep_t)+ rep_x),(sizeOfCirlce*cos(rep_t)+rep_y),defaultColors(1,:),'edgecolor','none');
    alpha(scatterPoints,opacity);

end
```