# Scatter plot with density in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, density-plot

I would like to plot data set 1 and data set 2 in one plot vertical. Unfortunately the data is huge, so it is just a smear of points and can't see the density. I tried hist3 and other suggestions but it overwrites my data sets and the binning looks awful.

Is there another way to plot scatter density plots? Is there really no Matlab function for it? If not, which program could I use to easy generate such a plot?

A mix between this two examples:

[image: Example1]

[image: Example2]
<sub>(source: [bcgsc.ca](http://www.bcgsc.ca/people/malachig/htdocs/alexa_platform/alexa_seq/FL_Trans/images/HS1361/ExonRegionVsGeneExpression_Log2.jpeg))</sub>

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I get the question - but wouldn't having  semitransparent circles solve your problem? The density would be higher in darker places (due to more circles overlapping there).

If that's good enough, it can't be done (afaik) by "standard" means (setting alpha of a plot/scatter), but there is a workaround using patches (which can be semitransparent), see, e.g., [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366404/semi-transparent-markers-in-matlab-figures]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*Thanks to [@Emil Albert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5992975/emil-albert) for a correction (a transpose was missing)*

---

What's wrong with computing [`hist3`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/hist3.html) and displaying the result with [`imagesc`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html)?

```
data1 = randn(1,1e5); %// example data
data2 = randn(1,1e5) + .5*data1 ; %// example data correlated to above
values = hist3([data1(:) data2(:)],[51 51]);
imagesc(values.')
colorbar
axis equal
axis xy
```

[image]

---

If you want to have **the axes in accordance with the true data values**: use the second output of `hist3` to obtain the positions of the bin centers, and pass them to `imagesc`:

```
data1 = randn(1,1e5); %// example data
data2 = 2*randn(1,1e5) + 1.2*data1 + 4; %// example data correlated to above
[values, centers] = hist3([data1(:) data2(:)],[51 51]);
imagesc(centers{:}, values.')
colorbar
axis xy
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way I can use hold on/off in the above example?

Comment: @C.Colden Sure. You can use `hold on` and plot lines on it. Try for example `hold on; plot(1:50,1:50,'k--','linewidth',1.5)` after my code

Comment: Is there a way to make the x,y axis correspond to the actual random numbers taken? I'm sure the concentration of the random numbers are not close to the point (25,25) as the graphic suggests. Would be more informative if this is possible.

Comment: @Integral To see the actual numbers you could use `plot` or `scatter`,  which plot a marker at the numbers. In my code above, use `plot(data1, data2, '.', 'markersize', .1)`. But if you have many points it's hard to distinguish them

Comment: @LuisMendo The problem with plot or scatter is that you lose the density. I really wanted to have exactly the same image but changing only the axis.

Comment: @Integral I think I understand now. Please see edited answer

Comment: That's it! You understand perfectly. Thank you for editing, it helped me a lot.

Comment: @Integral Glad I could help :-)

Comment: It looks to me that for getting the correct orientation in the density plot, one needs to do imagesc(values'), that is the transpose of the matrix, instead of imagesc(values). The density matrix returns the values where the rows contain the density of first data column, and columns contain the values for second data column.

Comment: @EmilAlbert Thanks for the edit. You are right, a transpose was missing. I have updated the images

Answer (score 2):

Try [Violin Plot](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23661) submission on File Exchange. It's very customizable. I use it all the time. Thanks to @Jonas.