# Matlab Hist3/Imagesc Axis Scaling

Tags: matlab, histogram, scale, matlab-figure, axis

I have 2 arrays of data `x` and `y` both are 22250-by-54, and I'm trying to use `hist3` and `imagesc` to make density plots for each `x(:,n)` and `y(:,n)` pair where `n = 1:54`.

I'm using `imagesc(values2)` where:

```
values2 = hist3([x(:) y(:)],[round(max(x)) round(max(y)) ]);
```

to use as my argument to plot for each of the 54 `x` and `y` values to get a unique axis range and it works fine. However, when I place fixed integer values for `values2` such as

```
values2 = hist3([x(:) y(:)],[50 50 ]);
```

the actual values for each of the 54 columns of `x` and `y` end up getting scaled to the [50 50] parameters or if I use [100 100] and it does not reflect the ACTUAL values for each `x` and `y`. How can I fix the axis `x,y` ranges and keep the actual values in the fixed axis range?

I have tried also using `xlim` and `ylim` in a separate call after the call to `imagesc(values2)` and this does not work either - it plots my data in a very small area and leaves lots of white space around the image area.

Thank you for your help!!

I have tried the "checked" response from the link below to get to where I am now:
[Scatter plot with density in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006490/scatter-plot-with-density-in-matlab)

Comment: The x axis and y axis values or range of data are not equal.  The x variable is wind speed and the y variable is temperature.  Thank you,

Comment: An expected range for the x variable might be 0 to 30 (wind speed) and the expected y variable range for temperature to include all 54 cases might be -20 to +40.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi - yes, that works in the same way that my current code works.  The x and y axis ranges are changing with each new plot.  This is not what I need.  I want to compare the spread of the data with the same or fixed x and y axis range for each case above for n, where n = 1:54.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [answer you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21008302/2627163) you can write:

```
% some arbitrary data:
x = randi(30,30,54);
y = randi(61,30,54)-21;

% constant values for every n:
nbins = [round(range(y(:))) round(range(x(:)))]+1;
x_lim = [min(x(:)) max(x(:))];
y_lim = [min(y(:)) max(y(:))];

% plotting:
for n = 1:9
    [values2, centers] = hist3([x(:,n) y(:,n)],nbins);
    subplot(3,3,n) % this is just for compact demonstration
    h = imagesc(centers{:},values2.');
    title(num2str(n))
    xlim(x_lim) % keeping the x-axis limits constant
    ylim(y_lim) % keeping the y-axis limits constant
    axis xy
end
```

Note that you may get with areas for your plots, as in this example, if the data in `x(:,n)` or `y(:,n)` has a smaller range then `y(:)` and `x(:,n)`.

which will give:
[image: imagesc hist]

Comment: i've tried your solution.  first plot is ok.  Second plot in the loop or when n == 2, I get an error on the values2 variable "Index exceeds matrix dimensions".  Your thoughts?  Also, the axis labels or x and y tick labels are in decimal form rather than integers.  thanks,

Comment: I run this in a loop with no error, can you copy the line that makes the error? as for the labels, this can be edited using `sprintf` I would add it to the answer, but I'm not sure what you want to see

Comment: values2 = hist3([y(:,n) x(:,n)],[round(range(y(:,n))) round(range(x(:,n)))]) ;

Comment: I figured it out the error but my axis are still changing values with every n plot.  I need them to be static - no changing.  Thanks,

Comment: It is possibles, but then you may get white strips from the sided if the data in `x(:,n)` and / or `y(:,n)` has a smaller range then `y(:)` and `x(:,n)`. Keep in mind that if you want to compare all the plots, you should use the same binning, so instead of `[round(range(y(:,n))) round(range(x(:,n)))]` you would have `[round(range(y(:))) round(range(x(:)))]` for all `n`. See my edit to the answer.