# Exhibiting the correct axes values when making plot with density in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, density-plot

I'm trying to make a plot with density of the zeros of random quadratic monic polynomials in the complex plane. In fact, I am plotting! But there is just a little detail which is bugging me: the values of the axes are not matching with the points in the plot. Here is my code.

```
n=2;
p = [1 random('Uniform', -1, 1, [1,n])]
roots(p)
z = zeros(0);
n = 2;
for j=1:10000
    p = [1 random('Uniform', -1, 1, [1,n])];
    R = roots(p);
    z = [ z, R.' ];
end
Re = real(z);
Im = imag(z);
[values, centers] = hist3([Im(:) Re(:)],[1000 1000]);
imagesc(centers{:}, values,[0,10]);
colorbar
axis equal
axis xy
cmap = summer(max(values(:)));
cmap(1:1,:) = 0;
colormap(cmap);
```

Now here is the plot generated by this code.

[image: plot]

You can try this code and check max(Re) and max(Im), which correspond to the maximum values of the real part (x axis) and imaginary part (y axis). I have max(Re) = 1.6076 (it's always something close to 1.5) and max(Im) = 0.9993 (it's always something close to 1). These values doesn't match the plot, which seems to be the opposite.

If I try the scatter function (losing density and all the nice visual), I have the right values. The following command generates the figure below.

```
scatter(Re(1,:), Im(1,:),'.')
```

[image: scatter]

This clearly shows that the first plot is actually(not rotated as I was thinking first) correct, except for the axes values. I need a help to fix this. Thanks.

**PS:** The commands to make this plot I got in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006490/scatter-plot-with-density-in-matlab/21008302#comment64041134_21008302). Note the comments there. I explicitly asked for a solution for this problem and got one. The given solution actually worked in some cases but failed in this one, I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for should be:

```
imagesc(centers{[2,1]}, values,[0,10]);
```

Incidently, you did not spot the problem in the other post is because the sample images all happen to be more or less square.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I made a search and the command  



   **imagesc(min(Re):.00001:max(Re),min(Im):.00001:max(Im), values,[0,10]);**




worked just fine. Do you know what is the difference between this command and yours?

Comment: In image/imagesc, only the x(1)/y(1) and x(end)/y(end) will be used, the rest of these vectors are completely irrelevant. i.e. x might as well just be [min(Re) max(Re)] and you will still get the same result. As long as you put Re as x and Im as y, you are good to go. Using centers is just a way to guarantee you get the same lower/upper bound as hist3 used, without worrying about how they are actually calculated by hist3.