# Plot (x,y,z) triplets over coordinates (x,y) with color z

Tags: matlab, plot

I've got a list of points (x,y,z) and would like to visualize them as a curve on a plane with points on (x,y) and any of color/intensity/thickness as z. How can this be done in Matlab?

`plot(x,y)` gets the right shape, but I need the color to depend on `z`.

Comment: do you want the line to change color as well or just the points?

Comment: Preferably both, but I have enough data that I could plot just the points without connecting lines.

Comment: For the sake of completeness I added some remarks regarding dependent intensity and thickness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't care about the color of the actual line, but the markers. Use `plot` in combination with `scatter`.

Imagine following example data:

```
t = 0:pi/20:2*pi;
x = sin(t);
y = cos(t);
z = t;

plot3(x,y,z);
```

[image]

Plotted in the 2D-plane:

```
plot(x,y); hold on
scatter(x,y,300,z); hold off
```

results in:

[image]

From your comment: if you have enough data and you don't need the line, just use `scatter`, it's exactly what you need.

---

Another possibility inspired by a [solution on MATLAB Central](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/5042-how-do-i-vary-color-along-a-2d-line), considering both line and markers.

```
surface([x;x],[y;y],zeros(2,length(t)),[z;z],'EdgeColor','flat',...
        'Marker','o','MarkerSize',10,'MarkerFaceColor','flat');
```

[image]

---

Make the color dependent on `z` is quite easy, for changing marker sizes you definitely need the `scatter` function:

```
surface([x;x],[y;y],zeros(2,length(t)),[z;z],'EdgeColor','flat'); hold on
MarkerSize = round(z*1000)+1;
scatter(x,y,MarkerSize,z,'.','MarkerFaceColor','auto'); hold off
```

[image]

For on `z` depending, increasing transparency it's a little tricky. You can find a workaround [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366404/semi-transparent-markers-in-matlab-figures), using the `patch` function.

Answer (score 2):

The solution can be like that

```
x = 0:.05:2*pi;
y = cos(x);
planez = zeros(size(x));
z = x;  % This is the color, vary with x in this case, but you can use your vector
surface([x;x],[y;y],[planez;planez],[z;z],...
        'facecol','no',...
        'edgecol','interp',...
        'linew',2);
```

The point is that you are painting a surface, where the colors can easily modified. I dont think it can be done with `plot`

[image]