# Plot lots of points with alpha value in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, transparency, matlab-figure, scatter

When you want to plot scatter points with fixed **alpha** value in Matlab, you may the `patch` function, like advised in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366404/semi-transparent-markers-in-matlab-figures). But when you want to plot a **high number** of individual points, you should use the `plot` function, as advised in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302623/matlab-scatter-plots-with-high-number-of-datapoints).

Is it still possible to plot a **high number** of scatter points with fixed **alpha** value in Matlab ?

Comment: If you have a sufficiently high number of points so that you're covering the region you're interested in, is a better approach perhaps to bin the points (with a 2D histogram) and then use `images`, so that this becomes more like a simple density map?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have matlab in front of me right now, but what I can contribute with is that, the properties of an object in matlab can be listed using `get(objectHandle)`. If there is an alpha value here it is possible to set it. Each handle also contains references to parent handles and child handles.

Comment: @GJStein: A density map would be fine if the scatter points have all the same color value. But when you want to deal with a vector of color values, it requires more effort to compute "at hand" the mixture of corresponding colors...