# querying for existence of a MATLAB figure window

Tags: matlab, plot

This is a followon to [Semi-transparent markers in Matlab Figures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366404/semi-transparent-markers-in-matlab-figures) , where one answer shows how to use `patch` to generate semitransparent circles at each data point.  What I want to do is use the axes' limits to adjust the circles so that they plot as circles when the x and y ranges are significantly different, causing true circles to plot as ellipses.  For the record, I don't have MATLAB 2014/15 so can't use the "hidden" handles discussed at the linked question.

So,  here's the problem: I want to query the current axes for their limits via `xlim` and `ylim` and use the results to adjust the `patch` circle shapes.  But if there is no figure window, `xlim` creates a new one.  Is there a command in  MATLAB that I can use to determine whether there is a figure window in existence ? My intent is to plot the `patch` objects in an existing graph when one exists.

If my approach is worthy of  [thedailywtf](http://thedailwtf.com), please suggest a more sensible way to do what I want to do, i.e. plot objects which are visually circles in a graph with arbitrary x- and y- axis ranges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the explicit question, see [`findall`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findall.html)

A simple test:

```
h.myfig = figure();
figures = findall(0,'type','figure');
```

And `h.myfig == figures` returns `1`, so it's finding our figure window.

Answering whether or not it's the best approach would require some example code showcasing your methodology.