# How can I get the length of a single unit on an axis in matplotlib, in pixels?

Tags: python, matlab, plot, matplotlib

I want to make [`markersize`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_markersize) equal to a single unit in height.  It seems that `markersize` is in pixels.  How can I get at how large "1 unit" (along a given axis) is, in pixels?

Comment: Like, but not a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893513/plot-circles-with-alpha-values-in-matlab you might find that useful though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at the [Transformations tutorial](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/transforms_tutorial.html) (wow, that took a lot of digging to find -- !)

In particular, `axes.transData.transform(points)` returns pixel coordinates where (0,0) is the bottom-left of the viewport.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# set up a figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.005)
y = np.exp(-x/2.) * np.sin(2*np.pi*x)
ax.plot(x,y)

# what's one vertical unit & one horizontal unit in pixels?
ax.transData.transform([(0,1),(1,0)])-ax.transData.transform((0,0))
# Returns:
# array([[   0.,  384.],   <-- one y unit is 384 pixels (on my computer)
#        [ 496.,    0.]])  <-- one x unit is 496 pixels.
```

There are various other transforms you can do -- coordinates relative to your data, relative to the axes, as a proportion of the figure, or in pixels for the figure (the transformations tutorial is really good).

TO convert between *pixels* and *points* (a point is 1/72 inches), you may be able to play around with `matplotlib.transforms.ScaledTransform` and `fig.dpi_scale_trans` (the tutorial has something on this, I think).